# why must use else in the recursive function to get a whole arrangement

Tags: c, recursion

if don't use else, the answer will be only one .just like 11111...111, when use else, I can get the right answer.
the codes:

```
void f(int cur, int n)
    {
        if(cur == n)// print answer
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            printf("%d", A[i]);
            printf("\n");

        }
        //else  no else no whole answer
        for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {
            A[cur] = i;
            f(cur + 1, n);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you add what your function is supposed to do. From its name `f` it's hard to reason about its intention

Comment: I'm no expert in c, are you aware that after your first `for` loop you are executing only the first expression? It does not seem so from the indentation level.

Comment: if `cur` reaches `n` then there's no need to call your `f` function, you already printed the result. That's why you need `else`.

Comment: What is the supposed output?

Comment: @halex, @CiaPan: It's an attempt to generate all the possible vectors of length `n` that contain values from `1` to `n` (i.e. the [Cartesian power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product#Cartesian_power) of the set of first `n` positive integers).

Answer (score 0):

If you do not add else then, when `cur == n`, your function will also execute this `for` statement:

```
   for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {
            A[cur] = i;
            f(cur + 1, n);
        }
```

But when you do, each time your condition is true you will only execute

```
if(cur == n)// print answer
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            printf("%d", A[i]);
            printf("\n");

        }
```

instead of both.

Answer (score 0):

Without that `else` the code never stops.

Each call of function `f()` checks `if (cur == n)`, prints something if this is true then, no matter the above condition, it enters the `for` loop. On its first iteration it calls itself with the next value of `cur` and everything repeats forever.

Well, not really forever. Since at every call it writes in the `A` array without any bounds checking, sooner or later it will attempt to write at an address that is not writeble and the SO will kick in and forcibly terminate the program.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let's imagine cur == n. (cur = 3 and n = 3)

Then `f()` would print the output, but it also continuous with the rest of the code.

So if `f(3, 3)` would be called, after the printing the `A[]` array it would continue with the second for loop calling `f((3 + 1), 3)` and this again would call `f((4 + 1), 3)` and so on, forever (or when your program crashes due to out of bound memory).

Conlusion: your function should stop at a moment and return to terminate, which it doesn't.